# To denote a training example should I use row vector or column vector?

Tags: terminology, notation

This code accesses the first 3 examples in the iris data set,

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
print(iris.data[:3])
```

and gives

```
[[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2]
 [4.9 3.  1.4 0.2]
 [4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2]]
```

To denote the first example, $x_1$, should I use a column vector like

\begin{bmatrix}
5.1\\3.5\\1.4\\0.2
\end{bmatrix}

or a row vector like the following?

$$[5.1 \ 3.5 \ 1.4 \ 0.2]$$

[Andrew Ng](https://youtu.be/eqEc66RFY0I?list=PLkDaE6sCZn6Ec-XTbcX1uRg2_u4xOEky0&t=360) suggests putting examples in columns

[image]

while typical relational databases putting examples in rows.

I'd just like to know the pros and cons of different notations so that I can decide which one I would follow.

Comment: Hello. What do you mean by "to denote a training example..."? Are you writing e.g. a paper or a homework and you don't know which notation you should use or maybe something else?

Comment: @nbro Thank you. I'd just like to know the pros and cons of different notations so that I can decide which one I would follow.